Solving a Fokker-Planck equation with discontinuous drift coefficients
Recently I'm trying to solve a Fokker-Planck equation corresponding to a piecewise-linear diffusion process with discontinuous coefficients. Namely, I'm dealing with the equation
\begin{equation}\label{FPE}\tag{1} \mathscr L^\dagger \rho=
{\partial^2\rho\over\partial x^2}+{\partial^2\rho\over\partial y^2}+x{\partial \rho\over\partial x}+(1+\alpha\Theta(-x))y{\partial \rho\over\partial y}+2(1+\alpha\Theta(-x))\rho = 0
\end{equation}
and seeking for a solution $\rho_{\rm eq}$ standing for the equilibrium state. Here $\Theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function and $\alpha>0$ is constant.  
Strictly speaking, the equation \eqref{FPE} should be rephrased as
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\label{integral}
\int (\mathscr L f) \rho_{\rm eq} = 0,\ \forall\ \text{smooth test function}\ f
\end{equation}
When $x<0$ or $x>0$ the Fokker-Planck equation can be rewritten as
\begin{equation} \mathscr L^\dagger\rho=\left\{\begin{aligned}&\Delta\rho+(\nabla\Phi_1)\cdot \rho+(\Delta\Phi_1)\rho&x<0\\&\Delta\rho+(\nabla\Phi_2)\cdot \rho+(\Delta\Phi_2)\rho&x>0\end{aligned}\right.\end{equation}
in which
\begin{equation}\Phi_1 = {1\over 2}(x^2+(1+\alpha)y^2), \Phi_2={1\over 2}(x^2+y^2)
\end{equation}
Clearly, when $x<0$ or $x>0$ we have the local solutions
\begin{equation}
\rho_{i}={1\over Z_{i}}\exp(-\Phi_i),\ i=1,2
\end{equation}
with $Z_i$ constants. But it seems that a simple "gluing up" cannot give a global solution to equation \eqref{FPE}, and I guess it's because the discontinuity of Heaviside function introduces singularity into the solution, and a global solution might be
written as
\begin{equation}\tag{3}\label{guess} \rho_{\rm eq} = {1\over Z_1}\mathbf 1_{x<0}\exp(-\Phi_1)+{1\over Z_2}\mathbf 1_{x>0}\exp(-\Phi_2)+F\end{equation}
where $F$ is a generalized function accounting for the boundary terms in the integration by parts formula(used to solve equation \eqref{integral}) at the discontinuity point $x=0$ of $\Theta(-x).$
Unfortunately, I tried the delta function and some other candidates for the distribution $F,$ but ended up in vain.  :(

Question: 1.  Is my guess \eqref{guess} correct? If yes, then how can I  gain more insights into the properties of the distribution $F$? If not, is there any good method to solve such equations with discontinuous coefficients?
2. Would the discontinuity of the coefficients affect the uniqueness and ergodicity of the solution to the Fokker-Planck equation \eqref{integral}? Any help will be appreciated. Recommendation of related literature is welcomed.
